# Can I replace pretty-config.xml configuration with annotations

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, url-rewriting, annotations, prettyfaces

I use the configuration file `pretty-config.xml` to rewrite urls:

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0
                                        http://ocpsoft.com/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.0.xsd">



    <url-mapping id="connect_ss">
        <pattern value="/sicav_security" />
        <view-id value="/AuthentificationSS.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>
    <url-mapping id="connect_oblig">
        <pattern value="/sicav_oblig" />
        <view-id value="/AuthentificationCAPOBLIG.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>
</pretty-config>
```

Can I replace it with annotations?

Comment: What exactly is your question? I don't get it. :)

Comment: @chkal: His original question was formulated using French grammar which is indeed confusing when individual words are literally translated to English without considering grammar. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking whether it is possible to configure PrettyFaces using annotations.

Yes, that is possible. You can simply use `@UrlMapping` for that:

```
@URLMapping(id="connect_ss", pattern="/sicav_security", 
       viewId="/AuthentificationSS.jsf")
public class SomeBean {
  /* Your code */ 
}
```

Have a look at this part of the official documentation for details:

http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/Configuration.html#config.annotations

Comment: nice, it's what i look for